# android getsharedPreferences not sure how to show hide other activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I decided to use sharedPreferences so I could store the value of a togglebutton on my activity Preferences. On my main activity I want to hide a twitter button when the user clicks the twitter button in the Preferences activity.

```
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
private String prefName = "MyPref";
private ToggleButton timer, twitter;
// this is the key used to set the timer to visible or hidden
private static final String TIMER_KEY = "timekey";
private static final String TWITTER_KEY= "tweet";
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preferences);
        timer = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.timer_pref);
        twitter =(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.twitter_pref);
        timer.setChecked(true);
        twitter.setChecked(true);
       // Toast.makeText(Preferences.this, timer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_btn);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        // now add the new screen


            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // get the shared perference data





                Intent i = new Intent(Preferences.this, AndroidGUIActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

         twitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0 );
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

                if (timer.isChecked() == true)
                {
                editor.putBoolean("twitterButtonStatus", true);
                }
                else if(timer.isChecked() == false)
                {
                    editor.putBoolean("twitterButtonStatus", false);    
                }


                // now save the value that is passed to the editor.putBoolean function
                // the twitter data hase been saved
                editor.commit();

                // now store the variable so that it can be copied to another activity
                Bundle b = new Bundle();


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to transfer Preferences through activities using intent.

You can access your "shared"Preferences from any activity.

You just put the button status with a string key inside:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("twitterButtonStatus", buttonStatus);
```

And in another activity you retrieve these preferences using string key ("twitterButtonStatus"):

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
boolean buttonStatus = settings.getBoolean("twitterButtonStatus", false);  // second param is default!
```

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Edit:

Youre saving SharedPrefs now, to get them back and set your Button Gone do something like this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
boolean buttonStatus = settings.getBoolean(TWITTER_KEY, true);  //2nd is default
if(buttonstatus==false) twitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: added suggestion on the bottom

Comment: i have added some new code. I have used the first code blocked and the third code block to solve my problems.